# Wordpress - PHP to Call a Google Sheets Cell with a Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-sheets-api

I'm looking to use php code within wordpress to call a cell from Google Sheets with a query.

I have been told this can be done using wp_remote_get()

I would like to query the sheet for:

select A where B = 'X'

How can I do this, please? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, its not available in Sheets API as it parameter is `sheetId` and `range`. Try this [tutorial : Query a Google Spreadsheet like a Database](http://www.bohyunkim.net/blog/archives/2831#.Wz19HHYzZGF) which your url will look like this:
`https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20A%20where%20B%20%3D%20%27X%27&key=[API_KEY]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thank you, but this calls things into a table. I just literally want plain text of one cell?

Comment: Then you can try using apps script, check this [link](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/google-apps-script-fetch-databases-to-google-spreadsheet/)

Comment: @WillNicholls What's wrong with parsing a table into text?